# PHP update table

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a dummy application for basic PHP learning purposes, OK now my application loges a user into an account where user can do multiple things such as search products etc. One of the functions the user can do is to Edit the account details and this is where everything goes wrong for me. There are no errors displayed but when I submit the query by click 'edit account' button everything simes to work but when i check the database i find out that nothing is changed...

I am also aware of the SECURITY issues withing the codes but atm i want to establish basic functionality

userEditAccount.php:

```
<?php


session_start();


    include('connect_mysql.php');



        if(isset($_POST['Edit Account']))
        {

            $usernameNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]));
            $passwordNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]));
            $first_nameNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["first_name"]));
            $last_nameNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["last_name"]));
            $emailNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]));



            $dbusername = $_SESSION['username'];
            $editQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_id='NULL' username='$usernameNew', password='$passwordNew', first_name='$first_nameNew', last_name='$last_nameNew' , email='$emailNew' WHERE username='$edit'");


            if(!$editQuery)
            {
                echo mysql_error($editQuery);
                die($editQuery);
            }
        }

?>


<html>
<head>

<title>Edit Account</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header><h1>E-Shop</h1></header>

    <article>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <h1>Edit Account</h1>

<div id="login">
    <ul id="login">
    <form method="post" name="editAccount" action="userEditAccount.php"  >
        <fieldset>  
            <legend>Fill in the form</legend>
                <label>Select Username : <input type="text" name="username" /></label>
                <label>Password : <input type="password" name="password" /></label>
                <label>Enter First Name : <input type="text" name="first_name" /></label>
                <label>Enter Last Name : <input type="text" name="last_name" /></label>
                <label>Enter E-mail Address: <input type="text" name="email" /></label>
        </fieldset>
        <br />


                <input type="submit" value="Edit Account" class="button">



    </form>

</div>
    <form action="userhome.php" method="post">
    <div id="login">
        <ul id="login">
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="back" onclick="index.php" class="button">   
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</article>

<aside>
</aside>

<div id="footer">Text</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I will also include login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

    require('connect_mysql.php');


     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
     {

        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password'");
        $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($username && $password){

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE username='$username'");
        $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrow !=0){

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];         
        }

        if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword ){

            $_SESSION['username'] == $dbusername;
            header("Location: userhome.php");

        }
        else{
            echo "Incorect password";
        }

    }
    else{
        die("This user dosent exists");
    }
}
else{

    $reg = die("Please enter username and password");
}
}


?>
```

In my very own oppinion there problem lays somewhere in the SESSION or perhaps the query but i have gone through many different resources and it shouldn't be a problem....I might be missing something very fundomential or some LAME mistake :D

Comment: Why are your escaping your strings, then strip the slashes? Anyway you shouldn't use the mysql_* extension. Use PDO or Mysqli instead http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Where is your `userEditAccount.php`?  The form is submitting there but you didn't post it.

Comment: If you're just learning, learn to use prepared statements with the MySQLi or PDO extensions, rather than learning bad practises with the deprecated MySQL extension

Comment: I highly recommend [`RedBeanPHP ORM`](http://redbeanphp.com/) for dealing with all things `SQL`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. You use `if(isset($_POST['Edit Account']))`, but your submit button has no name:
`<input type="submit" value="Edit Account" class="button">`

Change the input to this:

`<input type="submit" value="Edit Account" name="edit_account" class="button">`

and change `if(isset($_POST['Edit Account']))` to `if(isset($_POST['edit_account']))`

Comment: I don't know if that's the case either, because it's submitting to `userEditAccount.php` but only `login.php` was posted.

Comment: Well spotted thx i made the changes but now i have this error message after clicking the button **Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\eshop\userEditAccount.php on line 22
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username='NewUser', password='000', first_name='Newname', last_name='NewLast' , ' at line 1**

Comment: Add the comma here user_id='NULL', username='$usernameNew'

Comment: line 22 of this script is $dbusername = $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: As @Sam says edit $editQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_id='NULL' username='$usernameNew', password='$passwordNew', first_name='$first_nameNew', last_name='$last_nameNew' , email='$emailNew' WHERE username='$edit'"); to $editQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_id='NULL', username='$usernameNew', password='$passwordNew', first_name='$first_nameNew', last_name='$last_nameNew' , email='$emailNew' WHERE username='$edit'"); And you did not set session for username

Comment: Your $dbusername is null because your session is not set.

Comment: this two queries are identical....? well i did set session in login.php that holds the users username.....                     `$dbusername = $row['username'];  `                      `$_SESSION['username'] == $dbusername;` and if thats wrong how do i do it then...?

Answer (score 0):

Where's $edit?

```
WHERE username='$edit'
```

Maybe you must change this with the $dbusername of the session

Hovewer:

-Don't use mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or pdo

-You can secure all vars in a single line

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $var) $_POST[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($var);
```

-Add validate control on input vars, and login session check

Comment: I changed the $edit with $dbusername variable and still nothing.  Well your are right about using PDO or mysqli but if I dont get the basic functionality first there is not point of making the code secure

Comment: Change also this value="Edit Account" in name="edit_account" as MIIB have write

Comment: i have done that and i get the following error now : **Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\eshop\userEditAccount.php on line 22
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username='1111', password='1111', first_name='1111', last_name='1111' , email='1' at line 1**